# Apple Volume Purchase Program

Tags: apple-vpp

We are developing a application that is to be used by our in house employees and few of our clients.

- Can we use Volume Purchase Program for the distribution of this app?
- Can same apple id used for developer account be registered for vpp account to distribute in house or any other app?
- If the app we are developing is free, does it cost anything for our clients if they distribute the app through their vpp account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 > Yes, VPP is best approach for in house app or business app.

Point 2 > No, For VPP you need another id you can not  use same developer account id for VPP.

Point 3 > You can distribute you app free or with cost. This cost  you define in application **Pricing and Availability** section.